# WordPress add metadata to custom column in posts list

Tags: wordpress

I have added a custom column 'rating' to wordpress posts list (in the admin):

```
function test_modify_post_table( $column ) {
    $column['rating'] = 'Rating';
    return $column;
}

add_filter( 'manage_posts_columns', 'test_modify_post_table' );
```

Is there any way to now populate it with metadata? I've searched all over, tried quite a few examples, but nothing seems to be working for me . Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following:

```
add_action( 'manage_posts_custom_column' , 'rating_columns' );

function rating_columns( $column ) {
    global $post;

    switch ( $column ) {
        case 'Rating':
            $metaData = get_post_meta( $post->ID, 'METADATA_NAME', true );

            echo $metaData;
        break;
    }
}
```

Just replace METADATA_NAME with the name of your ratings metadata